# Can I monitor a rolling window using Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What I'm looking to do within Cloudwatch dashboards is to monitor the performance of my application over 14 days, but re-evaluate that performance every hour. However, from everything I've tried so far, this doesn't seem to be possible within Cloudwatch dashboards.

So say for example, I have a metric which measures the success rate of my Lambdas. What I want is a rolling window that looks at the last 14 days of data every hour and plots this.

Is there any way to achieve this within Cloudwatch?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after or why. Why does it need to be one measurement every hour, rather than Cloudwatch defaults which is every 5 minutes, 1 minute for detailed metrics? You can change the graphed duration to any value including 14 days and CloudWatch will graph it.

Comment: What I want is to be assessing a window of say 5 minutes every minute - so each minute, assess the last 5 minutes of data.

So for example:
At 20:19 assess data from 20:14 - 20:19, at 20:20 assess data from 20:50 - 20:20

Comment: Can you be more precise about what "success rate" means? In short if you can push a metric into Cloudwatch you can graph it, or you can log to Cloudwatch logs.